# How can I stop cygwin updating ACL in windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, rsync

I'm using cygwin version 2.11.2, When creating a directory through my code with rsync , cygwin setting ACL which windows consider as "NULL SID".

I've gone through the help, tried updating /etc/fstab with "noacl" followed by reboot but no luck.

Is there any alternate way I can make cygwin not to update ACL at all or any way to guide cywin to update a proper ACL.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin is using proper ACLs, see for details
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html

assuming you are not interested in Cygwin POSIX permissions in some area of your disk,
like /cygdrive you can use the option `noacl` in `etc/fstab/`

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

Comment: Thank you, let me give more details!  I built a windows exe using cygwin and carried dll's (cygwin1.dll,cygpopt-0.dll,cyggcc_s-1.dll) along with the exe to other windows machine.  I tried the above mentioned cases in the cygwin where I had built the exe, but no luck. Where will those files (/etc/fstab,/etc/passwd,/etc/group) will be looked in windows machine when copied my exe and dll's to other machine? Thanks for ur help